# Dell Inspiron N1050 Battery Plugged In Not Charging

Tags: system, battery, batterylevel

I have a Dell Inspiron N1050 Laptop, Using it around 3 years and the battery status of my laptop, shows me a oragelight  while on windows and  when i switch off the laptop, which means the battery is deadth. So I recently purchased a batter for the laptop, But on windows it shows "Battery Plugged in Not charging" and when i switch off the charging status light shows none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can occur because of both software and hardware, in case of hardware, dead battery is one cause.

The other cause that I have faced, is damaged charging circuit and that is the worst, so find a good mechanic,else new mother board will be needed.

I my case that problem occurred because I had used a low quality charger.

Answer (score 0):

I have a HP laptop with Windows 7 and ran into the same problem, where the Windows task bar battery icon showed "plugged in, not charging". My solution was to:

1. hold down the power button
2. plug in the power cord
3. wait 5-10 seconds for the charging light to switch to amber
4. release the power button
5. push the power button again

This resolved my issue and the battery icon on the Windows task bar switched to "plugged in, charging".